# How can I click a radio button using agouti of Go?

Tags: go, agouti

I'd like to check the radio button by click. The html is as below.

```
<input type="radio" id="XXX_ZZZ" name="XXX_" value="ZZZ">
```

(The id, name, and value are incidentally not stable.)

I've tried the following codes:

```
page.Find("ZZZZ").Click()
```

However, I could not check it.

How can I click radio button under agouti environment?

Thanks!

Comment: `The id, name, and value are incidentally not stable.` Do you mean that these values are not constant and can always vary?

Comment: I'm sorry for my but English. Yes, it's always vary...